# Neural Networks for time series

Tags: neural-network

I have an understanding problem. I am a beginner in machine learning and have also a little experience in modelling NNs but not for time series.

But I cannot imagine how to use Neiural Networks for time series.

So if I want to train a Multilayer NN what is the input?

I read several papers about such ANN to predict time series. But they did not explain how actually.

Can I imagine it as follows: Is every input node a specific time stamp?

If I want to predict the value for time t+1, and I use 15 input neurons, so I use the values at each time stamp from t-15 upt to t?

How do I train such a NN?

I am a little confused.

Comment: if you are familiar with python language , there is good [explanation](https://github.com/llSourcell/How-to-Use-Tensorflow-for-Time-Series-Live-/blob/master/demo_full_notes.ipynb) about RNN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type of neural networks you are looking for to predicting timeseries are called **recurrent** networks; the previous neuron states in the network affect the new neuron states. Examples of such recurrent networks are [LSTM](http://colah.github.io/posts/2015-08-Understanding-LSTMs/), [GRU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gated_recurrent_unit) and [NARX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonlinear_autoregressive_exogenous_model).

If you have the data from t<sub>0</sub> to t<sub>10</sub>, and you want to predict t<sub>11</sub>, then you need to input the values from t<sub>0</sub>- t<sub>10</sub> *one by one* into the network. You have to train the network so that the output of t<sub>n</sub> is t<sub>n+1</sub>. So after you have inputted t<sub>10</sub>, the output will be the values predicted for t<sub>11</sub>.

Real life example: I want a network to keep on decreasing it's output until it has reached 1, and then make it output 0 to start over again:

```
in: 0.0, out: 0.2
in: 0.2, out: 0.4
in: 0.4, out: 0.6
in: 0.6, out: 0.8
in: 0.8, out: 1.0
in: 1.0, out: 0.0
```

*And that is what your training data should look like*

If it is still to complicated, I recommend you to play around with this front-end neural network library for the browser: [Neataptic](https://github.com/wagenaartje/neataptic). It is very easy to fiddle around with. [Example](https://jsfiddle.net/9t2787k5/4/)

Comment: Thanks. But what about this explanation? 
 It does use a normal NN,right? So where is the difference?
 https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/10196